# How to implement an utility type that tranforms the return type of any function type to a promise?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I wanted to write a utility type that is able to tranform any function type (including generic functions) to have a `Promise` as return type.

My idea was this:

```
type Promisify<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (...args: A) => Promise<R>
  : never;
```

Unfortunately this would not work for generics:

```
type Bar<T> = () => T extends string ? number: string

// ERROR: Generic type 'Bar' requires 1 type argument(s).
type PromisifyBar = Promisify<Bar>
```

In my actual case I want to transform function types declared in an interface (of a 3rd party library) and just change the return type:

```
interface Foo {
   baz<T extends { a?: string, b?: string}>(arg: T): T extends {a: string} ? string : number;
}

type Baz = Foo["baz"]
type PromisifiedBaz = Promisify<Foo["baz"]>

// Only type is relevant so skip implementaion
const baz: Baz = undefined as any;
const promisifiedBaz: PromisifiedBaz = undefined as any;

// CORRECT
const shouldBeNumber = baz({b: "b"});
// CORRECT
const shouldBeString = baz({a: "a", b: "b"});

// CORRECT
const shouldBePromiseNumber = promisifiedBaz({b: "b"});
// WRONG: it's of type Promise<number>
const shouldBePromiseString = promisifiedBaz({a: "a", b: "b"});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYEsDOKBmIA8AVKCAD2AgDsATNKACgDoGBDOAczQC4pGyQBKKALwA+LjxECoBYqUrV6TVhygoymCHCgBBfsOWr1UAEoAoKFAD8tBnWZtO2wSPjJ0EHIaGmonMhABu6gDcxiGgkFAAQsz44rS2nHg6IlIk5FRQaMBwKiwWUGQArkgARuqcmdlkLCEA9DVQAKKGhgDyhpwA4uTqKADGUGHQAORRcENQcBAAjgUok9QAjAPg0LZF5MA0aLx0xnXL4c6oGNijgrCIx1i4o57GKqRwmIy90ABiCAhQAN5eUMWMABe+EIqVkPy45nKWRyABp-lCMjCqgBfIQ0eKSXgJUEydLfRjQyosFF5Co5bz5IqlODBFGhFaRIHnD4IADaACIAYCOQBdYyDC4uE4oCAUKKA85HdDXHCszncvl3fYtMgAGxAB2g6AmEDV-m4wAyXzQAGsUGBlEgwPqkBtGCgEGRjL0nZl-kDOBLzgVKBBMCoxVxqNwQMFXWR3WBLjKA2KJZxpSL48yJL6KP7AxRg6Iw7V6gBhNqGBoFvAut1GtAACwQBTV4ogADlqQYJNyaN9ipwuRyUbxgvsi81S+WI+6a3WGxEIABlZG5dtAzuEqAcxgc+HdtfFPsD-NQYclssVyNV2v1xtJ5utjQSaPCrCi8XLrs93f9wf1ADqrSbHU4FBgCGagEEwLUoFPCcL2nCBr3nYlzgfK44xfQEVx7Dct3fPdAiAA)

As you can see it's working expect for the last `shouldBePromiseString`. I guess that there is an issue with type inference (see `infer A` in `Promisify`) which is why the return type is inferred wrongly.

How can I create such an utility type? Is it even possible?
Are there alternatives? Is there a better implementation for `Promisify` than my suggestion?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wO83MN) work for your needs? TypeScript lacks *higher kinded types* of the sort necessary to express the type manipulation you're trying to perform purely at the type level.  TypeScript 3.4 introduced [support for higher order inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) which does what you want but only when dealing with *values* of such types. It requires you to drop down to the value level before getting the types.

Comment: If that code works for you I can write up an answer; if not please let me know what's missing (although it's quite likely the answer would be "sorry, this is impossible").

Comment: @jcalz thanks! I mean it's clearily not a nice looking approach, but that's what TypeScript offers atm I guess. It answers my question so feel free to also add it as answer. If it doesn't work out for me well I will create a new question with more details about my actual use case.